# What function do I use to get the post text?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the function:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

To get the post title. I want to get the post text/the body which is the second field of the post but I don't know how. I tried two functions:

```
<?php the_content(); ?> and <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

They work but I get other things from wordpress plugins that are part of my post (like share buttons). I cannot disable these plugins. Is there any way to get what is in the second field without anything else?

Comment: @Lisandro `the_content()` is the correct way of pulling in the post body. If it's not working, then something else must be wrong, or things aren't set up correctly. Can you post any more info? Try turning off plugins if you're using any.

Comment: Yes, thanks: That function works but I also get Share buttons and other things that are part of the post instead of just the second field.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not very clear. If you want to get the post body, `the_content()` is how you get that. If you're using share buttons, etc., these are most likely separate plugins and will need to be adjusted in order for them to not show up where you don't want them. Are you using a `<!--more-->` tag?

Comment: The post body. The form users are using is has two fields, the title and the post itself or the body. I just copied the second field above. Tell me if there's anything else I can copy or tell you.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `input` that you posted has to do with the post, or with your share buttons. Try describing what is happening in as much detail as possible, and then explain what you *want* to happen.

Comment: Ok, normally I need the social media buttons so I cannot remove the plugin but in this particular case I want to get the content without any buttons, just the text alone. But the function the_content always shows the buttons, and I don't know how to get just the the text.  I'm not using the --more-- tag.

Comment: Ok...that might be a little trickier. I take it that the plugins don't have any way to turn if off for a certain post? You can do a custom call to the database - that may work. I'll post back in a minute with an example.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. Most likely, the plugin is using a hook to get it to the top/bottom of the post - it won't matter how you actually retrieve the post. Can you post what plugin you're using that you want to hide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a social media plugin installed that automatically adds facebook buttons etc. Have a peek inside your admin panel > plugins for any such plugin

Comment: That's exactly the problem, but I cannot disable the plugins. Isn't there a way round to get the second field through php without everything else?

Comment: Thanks I ended up disabling the plugin and calling it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that `the_content()` runs all the filters attached to `the_content`. Try calling `get_the_content()`, and echo its return:

> <?php echo get_the_content() ?>

If you want the filters applied, you can call:

> <?php apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content()) ?>

Answer (score -1):

A down-and-dirty way to hide the share plugin on certain posts could be using some simple jQuery like this:

```
$('post-id share-div-id-or-class').hide();
```

Not ideal, but other than modifying the plugin directly, you may not have a choice. You could repeat the above line for every post where you want to hide the sharing plugin.